# Update the data in View with AJAX not working

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have diffrent `<a>` tags that normally pass a parameter to an action using `asp-route=""`. Now i want to use AJAX t do this. each tag is supposed to pass an `ID` that comes from the model `chats` when the page loads up. (`asp-route-ChatID="@Model.ID"`).
How can I achieve this in AJAX and pass that parameter? I tried using `Data-ajax-update` and `Data-ajax-url` but these option arent even available in Intellisense. Here is the method that i want to call

```
  public IActionResult Chat(string ChatID)
    {
        Chats userchats=new Chats(); // a class that holds chats
         //selecting data from the database......
        
        return View(userchats);//returns view with the model
    }
```

here is the `<a>` tag that gets clicked and it needs to pass a specific `ID` that comes from the model

```
<a > View Chat </a>
```

here is the `<div>` that needs to be updated depending on what `<a>` is clicked

```
    <div id="UpdateThis">  <!--show data that comes from the method ajax calls-->   </div>
```

How can I implement ajax here with tag helpers or any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PartialView instead of view if you want to update div.

```
public IActionResult Chat(string ChatID)
{
    Chats userchats=new Chats(); // a class that holds chats
    //selecting data from the database......
        
    return PartialView(userchats);//returns view with the model
}
```

View

```
<a id="btnView" data-id="1">View Chat</a>
<div id="UpdateThis"></div>

<script>
   $("#btnView").click(function () {
      $.post('@Url.Action("Chat")', { ChatID: $(this).data("id") }).done(function (e) {
          $("#UpdateThis").html(e);
      })
   });
</script>
```

Comment: thank you for the help. what if that partial view is inside another view(the main view) but they have different Models?

Comment: that Data-id is editable by the user. If they edit the ID there im screwed. Is there a way that info stays on the server side?

Comment: you can use like { ChatID: @Model.ID }.

Comment: can use other model in partialview. based on your @model.